# Is it possible to paste with formatting in Mosaico?

Tags: mosaico, tinymce

I totally understand the benefit of plain pasting into Mosaico, but we have to quickly create an email with a ton of links and I simply want to copy, paste, but keep the formatting (bold, italics, etc) and hyperlinks.

Within mosaico, we just do copy paste of the source, and that works for us,  but this is coming from a word doc.

Any suggestions?

Comment: i don't know word at all, but is it possible to tell word to give you clean html, eg (from a quick google) Using MS Words built-in save as HTML option
Go to the file menu.
Select Save as.
In the drop-down file type box select, Web Page, Filtered.
Click Save.

Comment: Thanks for that - its an option for now! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question - this is possible now with the latest 3.x version of mosaico for civicrm.

Comment: good to know of the progress